# Give an intuitive explanation for the time complexity of Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

As we know, Dijkstra Algorithm has a time complexity of $O(|V|^2)$ using the adjacency matrix representation of the graph. I'm trying to explain this statement by giving an intuitive explanation. It is the following.

Let us consider, for example, that we would like to build, applying Dijkstra's algorithm, all paths of least weight starting from s and arriving at every other vertex of the graph:

[image]

The distance values are shown in the following table for each step of the algorithm:

[image]

We have 7 nodes and then a $7\times 7$ table. This is true also for a general graph for $n$ nodes: we will have a $n\times n$ table. For a complete graph, we have a table where we need to fill at most $n(n-1)$ entries (the first row is the initialization). Then we have a complexity of $O(n^2)$.

Comment: You need to argue *why* filling in the matrix is $O(n^2)$, i.e. why does step $i$ have complexity $O(n)$.